# Clear setTimeout and continue code execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a daemon and sometimes I made some pause. I want to allow user to cancel pause and continue code but I don't know how to do it. Here is my code. User clicks on 'Start' and the daemon starts. There is a pause of 30 seconds and if this same user interrupts this pause (with clearTimeout), I want to continue code execution after `await sleep(30000)` and print 'Continue'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Logs</p>

<button onclick="runDaemon()"> Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()"> Stop</button>

<script>
let currentSleep = -1;
let isRunning;

async function sleep(ms) {

  const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    currentSleep = setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  })

  console.log('Current sleep : ' + currentSleep);

  return promise
}

function stop() {
  isRunning = false
  document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = 'Clear Current sleep : ' + currentSleep;
  clearTimeout(currentSleep)
  document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = 'Current sleep cleared '
}

async function runDaemon() {
  isRunning = true;
  document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = 'This is the beginning';
  while (isRunning) {
    await sleep(30000);

    document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = 'Continue';
    console.log('Continue');
  }

  document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = 'The end';
  currentSleep = -1;
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please find the demo at this address

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GMKEN04TS0PF

Comment: so you want to print 'continue' one last time after user cancels/click on stop?

Comment: Printing 'Continue' is just for this example but I want to continue code after that, it can be another function or some other work